# Matching elements of a list to a data frame using R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match

*df* is a data frame that contains ids, *list* is a list of attributes. The first element of *list* contains the attributes for the first observation of *df*, and so on.

**How can I obtain a dataframe that matches ids with attributes?**

An example

```
set.seed(1)
df= data.frame(id=paste(rep("id",10),1:10,sep=""))
list=replicate(10,letters[sample(1:26,sample(1:3,1),replace=T)])

head(df)
# id 
# id1
# id2
# id3
# id4
# id5


head(list)
[[1]]
[1] "j"

[[2]]
[1] "x" "f"

[[3]]
[1] "y" "r" "q"

[[4]]
[1] "f"

[[5]]
[1] "r"

[[6]]
[1] "u" "m"
```

The first 5 observations of the resulting data frame should look like this

```
   id attribute
1 id1         j
2 id2         x
3 id2         f
4 id3         y
5 id3         r
```

Comment: Ragged arrays are no fun in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the `length` of each element of 'list' using `lengths` (introduced in `R 3.2.0`), replicate the 'df$id', `unlist` the 'list' and create a 'data.frame' with those vectors.

```
 res <- data.frame(id=rep(df$id,lengths(list)), attribute=unlist(list))
 head(res)
 #     id attribute
 #  1 id1         j
 #  2 id2         x
 #  3 id2         f
 #  4 id3         y
 #  5 id3         r
 #  6 id3         q
```

Or we can set the names of the 'list' with the 'id' column of the dataset ('df') and use `stack` to get the long form

```
  stack(setNames(list, df$id))
```

Or a similar approach with `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
  library(tidyr)
  unnest(setNames(list, df$id), id)
```

NOTE: It is better not to name objects with a function name (in reference to 'list', 'df')

Comment: @akrun `lengths` function?

Comment: @bergant It is introduced in `R 3.2.0`, basically a wrapper for `sapply(list, length)`, but way faster